# Display multiple headings using same mixin function

Tags: html, pug

I am writing one pug file in which I am trying to display the two tables vertically with their headers. The two tables are coming up but the second header should come up after the first table. But it's coming along with the first header.

Like in the enclosed picture I want the pending dispatch should come up after the first table but it's coming up below the dispatch records.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJFoP.png)

Here is my pug code :

```
mixin dispatch-summary(message)
  h1.align-left.font-bold DISPATCH RECORD
  tr
    th.align-center.font-bold S.NO
    th.align-center.font-bold Dispatch Id
    th.align-center.font-bold Projects
    th.align-center.font-bold Hardware
    th.align-center.font-bold Box Number

    each task,status in message
      -var dispatch_id= task.dispatch_id
      -var project = task.project
      -var hardware = task.hardware
      -var boxnumber = task.boxnumber
      -var dispatched = task.dispatched

      if dispatched==true
        tr
          td.font-bold=status+1
          td.align-center= task.dispatch_id
          td.align-left.project= task.project
          td.align-left.hardware= task.hardware
          td.align-left.boxnumber= task.boxnumber

  h1.align-left.font-bold PENDING RECORD
  tr
    th.align-center.font-bold S.NO
    th.align-center.font-bold Dispatch Id
    th.align-center.font-bold Projects
    th.align-center.font-bold Hardware
    th.align-center.font-bold Box Number

    each task,status in message
      -var dispatch_id= task.dispatch_id
      -var project = task.project
      -var hardware = task.hardware
      -var boxnumber = task.boxnumber
      -var dispatched = task.dispatched

      if dispatched==false
        tr
          td.font-bold=status+1
          td.align-center= task.dispatch_id
          td.align-left.project= task.project
          td.align-left.hardware= task.hardware
          td.align-left.boxnumber= task.boxnumber
doctype
html
  head
  body
    div
      .divider-padded
      table.table.withbackground.width-100
        +dispatch-summary(message)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample `message` value?

Comment: First, `h1` elements are [not permitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) to be immediate children of `table` elements. Try wrapping it in a `th` element. If that doesn't help, please also post your CSS.